# GREP in R, Extract matching lines from a list

Tags: r

I am trying to extract few lines from a list of 300 lines which is prepared from a set of PDF files in a directory.

All the pdf files are in a list of 300 lines. Now I want to extract lines that has a matching word.

```
library(stringr)
library(pdftools)
library(tm)
library(tidyverse)
library(rex)

#Directory with multiple pdf files
files<- list.files(pattern='pdf$')

#Extract all files content into a list
lapply(files, function(x) strsplit(pdf_text(x), "\n")[[1]]) -> result

#change the type for ease of processing
mylist <- unlist(result)  %>% str_split("\n")

#Squish all the words in a line together with space default
str_squish(mylist)

#Find lines that has a match with the mentioned string (ex: Table in t)
t  <- grep("Table",  mylist)
t1 <- grep("T[0-9]", mylist)
f  <- grep("Figure", mylist)
f1 <- grep("F[0-9]", mylist)
l  <- grep("Listing",mylist[1:300])
l1 <- grep("L[0-9]", mylist)
s  <- grep("Source", mylist)

# Output of t with indices where there is a match for string "Table"
> t
[1]  46  71  95 124 153 250 278

#Now how to print these indices values to a new list? or Do i go back to mylist and pass the indices numbers and extract it from mylist. What is the best way to do it ?
----------------------------
```

when I run these lines of code (t,t1,f,f1,l,l1,s) I get the indices of the matching string in that line.

[below is the image with output showing lines where it has a match.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Sn7.png)

Now I just need to print those lines to another list. How do I do that, Please advise.

Comment: Do you want the values in `mylist` that match `"Table"`, etc, or the values in `t`, etc? And do you want them in an object of class `"list"`?

Comment: Hi, If I run 't' with key word "Table" that gives me the line numbers when it finds a match in mylist. Now I want to extract that line from mylist where there is a match to a class object list.

Comment: I want complete character string of each matching line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without test data it's difficult to say, the code below is untested.

Put the patterns in a list and `lapply/grep` with `value = TRUE`. This returns a list with each member a vector of the matching strings.

```
search_list <- list("Table", "T[0-9]", "Figure", "F[0-9]", "Listing", "L[0-9]", "Source")
matches_list <- lapply(search_list, grep, x = mylist, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: Well, I have tested it for you sir, thats amazing. I tested on 66 files and it precisely pulled the matching strings.